# Regular Expression For Multiple Possibilities

Tags: php, regex

I have a piece of code that is extremely useful for substituting an email address with an actual link.  Sometimes email addresses have more than one suffix (ie: .co.uk vs .com).  I am able to create regex for each of these scenarios, however I'm curious if any regex gurus out there know of a way to combine the two into a single expression.  If so, could you please explain what your answer is and why it works?

Here is my current code -

```
$input = "here is a line of text, test@test.com, email@domain.com, email@domain.co.uk here";

preg_match_all('%\w+\@\w+\.\w+\.\w+%', $input, $matches);

$outmatch = Array();

if(is_array($matches[0])){
    foreach($matches[0] as $match){
        array_push($outmatch,$match);
    }
}

$outmatch = array_unique($outmatch);

if(is_array($outmatch)){
    foreach($outmatch as $outm){
        $input = str_replace($outm,'<a href="mailto:' . $outm . '">' . $outm . '</a>',$input);
    }
}

print $input;
```

Expression for 2 suffix: `%\w+\@\w+\.\w+\.\w+%`

Expression for 1 suffix: `%\w+\@\w+\.\w+%`

Comment: Why do you hate my `someone+something@example.com` emailaddress?

Comment: Because it's not natural!  Nice point, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I not aim to develop the perfect matching regex for matching email addresses in this post. I just want to help the questioner a little bit. :)

---

The following regex matches at least one domain and its tld but it allows for multiple subdomains.

```
preg_match_all('%\w+\@\w+\.\w+(\.\w+)?%', $input, $matches);
```

So it matches:

```
test@test.com

test@sub.test.com

test@subsub.sub.test.com
```

... and so on. But it would not match:

```
test@test
```

.. because the tld is missing.

---

Further note, that a valid email user name can contain chars like the dot `.` So `\w` would not match all possible addresses. So a bettern pattern might look like this:

```
preg_match_all('%[a-zA-Z0-9._\%+-]+\@\w+\.\w+(\.\w+)?%', $input, $matches);
```

---

Further note :) That a valid domain name can also contain numbers and special chars for example the `-` . This results in an regex like this:

```
preg_match_all('%[a-zA-Z0-9._\%\+\-]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.\w+(\.\w+)?%', $input, $matches);
```

---

Further note :) :) A valid email address can also look like:

```
test@192.168.0.1
```

.. no domain names. Also note that any email address without a tld is valid. You see to create a really *matching* email regex ins't that easy.

I would advice you to take one well documented from the web that has been elaborated during times.

Comment: Excellent!  So am I to assume that `()?` means anything in the parenthesis may or may not be present an unknown amount of times?

Comment: Yes, thats right. Refer to the preg syntax manual : http://php.net/manual/de/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: @GigaWatt Yes you are right. Read my updates. I wrote them while you commented. That's because domain names cannot be matched by simply using `\w`. They can contain numbers and special chars. like the `-`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you: `%\w+\@(?:\w+\.)*\w+\.\w+%`

It allows as many sub-domains or TLDs as necessary.  Here's [an example](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Cw%2b%5C@%28?%3a%5Cw%2b%5C.%29%2a%5Cw%2b%5C.%5Cw%2b&input=person@site.com%0Aperson@site.co.uk%0Aperson@my.site.co.uk) of it in action.

The `(?:\w+\.)*` means "zero or more occurrences of a sub-domain followed by a dot".  The `(?:` makes it non-matching.

Answer (score 0):

Use alternation ;)

```
preg_match_all('%\w+\@\w+\.\w+\.\w+|\w+\@\w+\.\w+%', $input, $matches);
```

Comment: Works great.  I'm going to keep that in mind for a different type of problem.